# Can MVC work with cshtml ending routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to route *.cshtml* ending urls to particular controller and action.

MVC pipeline blocks such urls and returns 404:

> The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been
>   explicitly forbidden.

However if `RouteExistingFiles` is set to `true` routing starts working but then all static files are routed and since I do not process these requests 404 is returned for images, css and js files. (Actually I don't want all requests for static content go through MVC pipeline.)

Setting `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />` changes the error to

> Type 'ASP._Page_Views_cshtml' does not inherit from
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.

and routing still does not work.

Comment: Why do you have routes ending with a protected system file type in your application?

Comment: @Well, this can certainly be done with extensionless routes, but I'd try with .cshtm. We want to use Razor views for angular's templates. Template controller catches requests for cshtmls in some predefined directories and returns corresponding view or forbidden.